# Flask app search bar

Tags: python, search, flask, full-text-search, whoosh

I am trying to implement a search bar using Flask, but when I enter the url/search, I got a 405 error, **Method Not Allowed**.

Here is a snippet of my code. Any help would be appreciated!

**forms.py**

```
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SearchForm(Form):
  search = StringField('search', [DataRequired()])
  submit = SubmitField('Search',
                       render_kw={'class': 'btn btn-success btn-block'})
```

**views.py**

```
from flask_login import login_required
from forms import SearchForm
from models import User

@app.route('/')
def index():
  if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('profile'))
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def profile():
  # some code to display user profile page

@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def search():
  form = SearchForm()
  if not form.validate_on_submit():
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
  return redirect((url_for('search_results', query=form.search.data)))

@app.route('/search_results/<query>')
@login_required
def search_results(query):
  results = User.query.whoosh_search(query).all()
  return render_template('search_results.html', query=query, results=results)
```

**models.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_whooshalchemy import whoosh_index
from app import app

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.model):
  __searchable__ = ['name']
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(64))

whoosh_index(app, User)
```

**search.html**

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% set page_title = 'Search' %}
{% block body %}
    <div>
        {{ render_form(url_for('search'), form) }} # note: render_form is some marco from another .html file
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can we see what's in the macro .html file?

Comment: can we used the same with nested dictionaries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because when you load page manually you using `GET` method, but only `POST` is allowed for `search` controller. You need to change

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
```

to

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

**UPDATE**

So basically it's better to change your `search` controller. Because it's not using *search.html* and works wrong.

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect((url_for('search_results', query=form.search.data)))  # or what you want
    return render_template('search.html', form=form)
```

Also make indentation 4 spaces, as it said in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Comment: Thanks, but when I add `'GET'`, I got 302 error now. It might be helpful that you see the index() in views.py so I just added it

Comment: A 302 isn't an error. It's the redirect that you send in `search`.

Comment: yeah but I got **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** and the search bar won't display on the search page

Comment: Thank you @vishes_shell! It works now. I made some edits to your answer. Thanks for reminding me of PEP-8, it's just I prefer Google 2-space indentation :p

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/products/',methods=['GET'])
def search():    
    search = request.args.get("search")
    search="%{}%".format(search)
    products = Product.query.filter(Product.name.like(search)).all()
    return render_template("abc.html",search=search, products=products)
```

Try to use port 80